# How to find good cloud device testing tool?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, test-management, mobile, qa-developer

I need to test my site on mobile and tab devices. But I don't have any real device for it.
Please help me to find a cloud device testing tool.

Comment: Do you have real devices OR you dont have?

Answer (score 1):

Their is  more cloud site present for testing in mobile devices.

(https://crossbrowsertesting.com/, https://www.browserstack.com/)

N.T-- They are all commercial Enterprise service. You can try a demo for these cloud services in some limited devices or some few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Both [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/features/#features-manual-testing) and [TestingBot](https://testingbot.com/features/manual-browser-testing) support manual and automated testing on real devices over the internet. You get a session to the device and can interact with it.

Also [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/) offers a similar service, but on virtualized devices. The other providers give the feelings its on real devices, but they could be virutalized too. This might also be something you could do yourself for free: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Also check the [Ripple Emulator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en) if your main focus is to test how your-sites look at different resolutions and mobile-browser features.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if below links are of any help to you:

Main providers of cloud services for mobile testing: like Perfecto Mobile, Keynote DeviceAnywhere, SOASTA, CloudMonkey and more can be found [here](http://qtp.blogspot.in/2015/02/mobile-application-testing.html). Moreover you can also find some examples of other mobile application testing tools.

[Here](http://qtp.blogspot.in/2012/10/cloud-testing.html) you can find companies providing cloud testing services or are involved in cloud testing services.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you are trying to check.

Worth checking out Mobile Device Labs right now in my opinion:

```
TestDroid
TestObject (Sauce labs)
Perfecto Mobile
NativeTap
Kobiton
Amazon AWS Device farm
Google FireBase
Xamarin Test Cloud
Experitest
Samsung Developers Lab
pCloudy
BrowserStack
```

There's also a crowdtesting option.
You can basically hire remote testers from a specific country which will have specific mobile device. It will be quite cheap if you want to do for example one test case, or short exploratory testing session.

For example:

```
http://www.utest.com/
https://www.testcloud.io/
http://www.testbirds.com/
https://crowdsourcedtesting.com/
https://www.pay4bugs.com/
http://www.mob4hire.com/
https://mycrowd.com/
https://test.io/
https://usabilityhub.com/
https://globalapptesting.com/
https://www.bugfinders.com/
http://www.usertesting.com/
http://whatusersdo.com/
http://trymyui.com/
```